# How to upgrade WampServer Version automatically?

Tags: upgrade, wampserver

I already have WampServer Version 3.0.4 32bit.

Now I want to upgrade to latest version.

Can I make like whenever there is a New Version of WAMP it will ask for upgrade like "Check for Updates" in most Softwares?

So every time I don't need to check weather latest version is available or not.

Comment: I will never understand why MS is unable to implement a working software management into their Windows systems which solved this for Linux systems in a convenient and reliable manner some 20 years ago......

Comment: To answer your question: no that is not easily possible, since software is usually distributed to MS-Windows systems in binary only form which does not allow to modify the installed software in any realistic way. What you _can_ do is use some scripting to compare the version string you read from the local installation with the version string scraped from some web site. The difference should be the information you need. A popup could then ask you to update, or you could even script the update itself. Though such home made solutions always bring a risk and require much effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not currently possible. However you could ask for this process to be considered and added to the **wish list** by posting a suggestion of the [WAMPServer Forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2)

You can also keep an eye on the [SourceForge repository](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/?source=directory) I imaging they have a feature that will tell you when new releases are added to their repo if you register with them. I personally think things are easier to find and better described on the [Backup Repository here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) and because we have to jump through a few hoops to get things onto SourceForge, is often a few days ahead of the SourceForge repo.

Since WAMPServer 3.x we have maintained a rather extensive set of ADDONS for new versions of Apache, MySQL, PHP and recently MariaDB and whereever relevant in both 32 and 64bit versions. These can now easily be applied to any WAMPServer 3 instance with 2 clicks, one to download and one to install.

As to your requirement to upgrade WAMPServer3.0.4. As of this date, the latest version of the WAMPServer software itself is WAMPServer3.0.8. This upgrade can be applied directly to your current 3.0.4 version without the need to install all the intermediary versions.

Finally, can I remind you that this handy software is developed and maintaned by a small group of people for you, for free.